# need network connection snackbar visible in all activities

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-snackbar

i have a snackbar in activity_container i need this snackbar in all activity

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(NetworkStateChangeReceiver.NETWORK_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                boolean isNetworkAvailable = intent.getBooleanExtra(IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE, false);
                String networkStatus = isNetworkAvailable ? "connected" : "disconnected";
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_container), "Network Status: " + networkStatus, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, intentFilter);
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a good idea, but why you don't make all your activity extends one which just create a snackbar when network connection is not available